# Simulating multi-user to operate PostgreSQL by Python？

Tags: python, postgresql, parallel-processing

I want to compare my distributed database and postgresql. So I need to simulate multi-user SQL operations on postgresql using Python.

Can I use the `mutliprocessing` module？

here is my code

```
 # encoding=utf-8
import datetime
import multiprocessing
import psycopg2

def exe(cmd):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = test user = pj password = dbrgdbrg")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        sql = "SELECT id FROM test WHERE ST_MAKEENVELOPE(118,38,119,39,4326) && wkb_geometry;"
        cur.execute(sql)
        print cur.fetchone()
    except Exception, e:
        print e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmds=range(5)
    for cmd in  cmds:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=exe,args=(cmd,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

But I don't know if it is correct? What should I do if I wanted to create random parameter to my SQL statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `random` function to generate random 'ST_MAKEENVELOPE` qualifiers this is assuming they belong to some range. And then use the random function to get 5 different ID's of ST_MAKEENVELOPE.

Another thing you can just use `for cmd in range(5):` instead of creating a list and then using it.

Comment: but  when I running   `sql = "SELECT id from test where id < random.randint(0,10) "`  it is prompt   `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: schema "random" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT id from test where id < random.randint(0,10)` 
                                       ^

Comment: `sql = "SELECT id from test where id < " + str(random.randint(0,10))`